# Sync Realm data across devices

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cloudkit

I have an app which uses Realm for data persistence. I recently made an iPad version of the App. I want that the user can use two devices iPad and iPhone (or more). And the realm data is synced across devices. Realms Cloud (mongoDB) is not a solution for me since i don't have the income to finance it. So i was thinking about CloudKit to use as a remote (changes) database.

My idea is that if the user used the app on iPhone for example and has generated a healthy amount of data, then when he installs the app on his/her iPad then first the whole database is sent over (using AirDrop) so that both of them are on the same state. Then the changes can be uploaded to CloudKit and synced to the destination needed.

My question is, how should i send only the changes to Cloudkit? (i don't want to store the whole database in the cloud because i think it is not necessary) And after the changes are uploaded i want that all devices can download them. What i don't know is, how should i check that all the iCloud connected devices have the changes? (Because i may consider deleting the changes uploaded if every device has received them).

I have tried using [SyncKit](https://github.com/mentrena/SyncKit) but it did not fit my needs because of my data model has one to many relationship.
The other library which i tried was [IceCream](https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream) but it was not reliable enough and still had some bugs when dealing with relationships.
And both of them are uploading the whole database instead of only the changes.

I hope someone can help me, or give some good advice, how to make a solution.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Are you stating you want to use Realm to store it's data in CloudKit? Is so, that can't happen directly. Realm only synch's with Realm cloud - keeping in mind Realm's lowest tier is free. Leveraging CoreData will be needed and if you're doing that, there's not need for Realm since it can be done in CoreData alone. Also sending the 'whole database' over airdrop will not be an effective solution - it's much better to sync small amounts of data ongoing than big chunks.

Comment: @Jay Airdrop would be used only the first time, to get the already huge data to the other device. Cloudkit would only sync the changes. I know realm cannot directly sync to CloudKit, thats why i want to convert the changed objects/data into ckrecords, upload to Cloudkit, fetch on other device an convert it back to a realm object. So i dont want to store anything in cloudkit, i just want to use it to send/sync data across devices.

Comment: You can use one to many relns with SyncKit Realm